# Cypress - can you use forEach loops?

Tags: cypress

I see tutorials and videos online showing the use of `forEach` in Cypress, for example:

```
someNames.forEach(({ name }) => {
  cy.findByLabelText('Enable').click()
  cy.findByText(`${name} enabled`)
})
```

Given that Cypress `cy.*` are asynchronous and `forEach` does no wait for async commands to complete, should `forEach` be avoided (in favour of using `cy.wrap(X).each()`)?

Comment: A better mental model for calling Cypress commands is adding to a to-do list. Your test runs, builds a plan, _then_ Cypress runs the plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypress **automatically waits** for the `cy.*` requests to finish before running the next one.

So there is no constraint to use `foreach()`.

It's often useful for example when you deal with DataTable (if using Cucumber)